# Membership service provider implemention

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm going to use membership provider for my Web App but I don't know how to create a database to check users membership against it.
Is there any tutorial or example for it?
visual studio 2012 creates database for membership service by creating MVC4 projects. Do I have to  create my database exactly like that or I can use some columns of its tables?

Comment: There exists neither tutorials nor examples anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any tutorial or example for it?

Here is an article for new [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)

> visual studio 2012 creates database for membership service by creating
>   MVC4 projects.

MVC 4 Project created by Visual Studio 2012 uses [Simple Membership Provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx). The main different is Simple Membership Provider supports OAuth.

> Do I have to create my database exactly like that or I can use some
>   columns of its tables?

You do not need to create database tables explicitly. Membership Provider will create required table by itself.

***Note:*** You cannot alter any tables created by Membership Provider such as adding a new columns to User table. If you do so, you will have to implement Custom Membership Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [article](http://odetocode.com/articles/427.aspx) Scott Allen, describes it a nice way.

Comment: not suitable article for my issue